# How to load a select choice-js with data from the database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, dropdownchoice, choices.js

I need to load a select choice-js with a list of countries and display the flag images. After making the Ajax request, I get a json (result.countries) and I don't know how to load the properties inside the custom html tags.
Does anyone know how to help me?

Asp.Net core Razor - Class

```
public  class ImageOptionViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; } //1
    public string Value { get; set; } //1
    public string Label { get; set; } //Brazil
    public string imageUrl { get; set; } //~/img/brasil.svg
}
```

Asp.net Core - Action

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("pais-gerenciar/obter-lista-paises-com-imagens")]
public JsonResult GetPaisesComImagens()
{            
    var paises = _paisAppService.GetAllBy(null, null).Select(x => new ImageOptionViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id.ToString(),
        Label = x.NomePtBr,
        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
        imageUrl = x.ImagemBandeiraURL
    });

    return Json(new { success = true, paises });
}
```

Asp.net Core - CSHTML

```
 <select class="form-control enderecamento-postal-sel-pais" asp-for="PaisId"></select>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pais-gerenciar/obter-lista-paises-com-imagens",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        stopLoader();

        if (typeof result.success !== 'undefined') {
            if (!result.success) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Ops...',
                    text: result.message,
                    icon: 'error',
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary w-xs'
                    },
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false
                });

                return false;
            }
        }

        let selPais = $(genericModalOrBodyInstance).find('.enderecamento-postal-sel-pais')[0];
        new Choices(selPais, {
            allowHTML: true,
            placeholder: true,
            renderChoiceLimit: -1,
            position: 'auto',
            resetScrollPosition: true,
            searchEnabled: true,
            loadingText: 'Carregando...',
            noResultsText: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado',
            noChoicesText: 'Sem opções para escolher',
            itemSelectText: 'Clique para selecionar',
            callbackOnCreateTemplates: function (template) {
                let classNames = this.config.classNames;
                let itemSelectText = this.config.itemSelectText;
                return {
                    choice: function (classNames, data) {
                        return template(`<div class="${String(classNames.item)} ${String(classNames.itemChoice)} ${String(data.disabled ? classNames.itemDisabled : classNames.itemSelectable)}"
                        data-select-text="${String(itemSelectText)}"
                        data-choice ${String(data.disabled ? 'data-choice-disabled aria-disabled=true' : 'data-choice-selectable')}
                        data-id="${String(data.id)}"
                        data-value="${String(data.value)}"
                        data-label="${String(data.label)}"
                        ${String(data.groupId > 0 ? 'role="treeitem"' : 'role="option"')}>
                            <img src="${String(data)}" alt="">
                            ${String(data.label)}
                        </div>`)
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    },
    error: function (e) {
        stopLoader();

        redirectToError(e.status);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to dynamically generate `option` in `select` according to the results returned by `ajax` requests? You can use the `setValue` property of choices.js.

For example, my ajax request returns an `ImageOptionViewModel` object:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPaisesComImagens()
{
    var paises = new ImageOptionViewModel()
    {
        Id = "1",
        Label = "TestLabel",
        Value = "1",
        imageUrl = "/img/img1.jpg"
    };

    return Json(new { success = true, paises });
}
```

My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetPaisesComImagens",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            //.....
            var myDynamicItems = 
            [
                {
                    value: result.paises.value,
                    label: '<img src=' + result.paises.imageUrl + '>' + result.paises.label,
                    id: result.paises.id
                }
            ]
            
            var start = new Choices(document.querySelector('.enderecamento-postal-sel-pais'), {
                allowHTML: true,
                placeholder: true,
                renderChoiceLimit: -1,
                position: 'auto',
                resetScrollPosition: true,
                searchEnabled: true,
                loadingText: 'Carregando...',
                noResultsText: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado',
                noChoicesText: 'Sem opções para escolher',
                itemSelectText: 'Clique para selecionar',
                callbackOnCreateTemplates: function (template) {
                    let classNames = this.config.classNames;
                    let itemSelectText = this.config.itemSelectText;
                    return {
                        choice: function (classNames, data) {
                            return template(`<div class="${String(classNames.item)} ${String(classNames.itemChoice)} ${String(data.disabled ? classNames.itemDisabled : classNames.itemSelectable)}"
                            data-select-text="${String(itemSelectText)}"
                            data-choice ${String(data.disabled ? 'data-choice-disabled aria-disabled=true' : 'data-choice-selectable')}
                            data-id="${String(data.id)}"
                            data-value="${String(data.value)}"
                            data-label="${String(data.label)}"
                            ${String(data.groupId > 0 ? 'role="treeitem"' : 'role="option"')}>
                                
                                ${String(data.label)}
                            </div>`)
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            start.setValue(myDynamicItems);

            return true;
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //.....
        }
    });
```

Test Result:
[image]